# Android Scroll Text in TextSwitcher

Tags: java, android

I have a texSwitcher to which I add two text views (created dynamically using TextView class). I am switching between the child text views using gesture detector. But when the text is large to fit in the current viewable area, the scrolling doesn't work for textswitcher.

When I tried using setTextMovement method of child text views, then the TextSwitcher stopped listening to horizontal swipe gestures.

Has anybody been successful in showing scrollable text views inside a TextSwitcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem with creating my own TextSwitcher.

```
public class MyOwnSwitcher extends ViewSwitcher {
    public MyOwnSwitcher (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyOwnSwitcher (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

I moved my "onTouchEvent"-Method into that new Class. Then I had to Override the "onInterceptTouchEvent"-Method like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I also had to move some of my Fields and Variables from my Activity to that new class.
But you can also use methods of your activity too with:

```
Activity ac = (Activity) this.getContext();
```

That should return your Activity.